# Add query parameter in the middle of the URL using react fetch

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am writing a service for all my RestApis where I store RestApis and then use it when I need by calling methods.

**RestApiService.js**

```
 let getData = 'https://myURL?id=123456';
export const getIndividualUsers = (resourceId) => {
    const queryParams = {
        userId: resourceId
    };
    
        queryParams.authorization = sessionStorage.getItem("authorization");

    }
    
    Object.keys(queryParams).forEach((k) => {
        queryParams[k] = (typeof (queryParams[k]) !== 'string') ? JSON.stringify(queryParams[k]) : queryParams[k];
    });
    return getData.get('', queryParams);

};
```

I call this method when I need data using the method name and use the response in my code:

```
getIndividualUsers(123456).then((response));
```

Now one of my API has variable in the middle of the URL such as

URL: 'https://myURL/${variable}/children/12'

How do I pass queryParams(variable) in the middle of the Url? I will have variable value when I call the method that fetches the URL and not while defining the the URL.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you asking how to use templated strings? Also, query params would be part of the query string ***at the end*** of the URL, not anything in the middle of it.

Comment: No, not templated strings but basically add variable value at the middle of the string. In addition to the queryParams at the end. Because I define URL in the service and I will have variable value when I call the method that fetches the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Which library are you using? Anyway you can do like below always.

```
const getChild = (parentName, id) => {
  let url = `https://myURL/${parentName}/children/${id}`;
  ...
};
```